# Does a loop invariant need to be defined both before and after the loop?

Tags: algorithm, loops, code-analysis

I've been really confused so far about loop invariants and their specific properties. Do they need to be true both BEFORE and AFTER the loop? Or just at some point in the loop body itself?

For example:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sum += i
}
```

The invariant would be that sum is equal to 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + i. You could say at the end of the second iteration where i = 1, sum = 1. That works, but the invariant needs to be valid in the beginning of the iteration too - and it isn't. Sum is 0 before the loop starts, violating that invariant. Is that correct?

Comment: there is no restriction on what `sum` "needs" to be. it doesn't affect the loop at all. The condition of the loop is only `i <10` while this is true an iteration will occur. I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: Your invariant is `sum == (0 if i <= 0 else 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + i-1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the loop invariant needs to be defined and true both before and after the loop.

Here is the fully annotated code. We have turned the `for` loop to a `while`, for clarity. We define an empty sum (`i-1<0`) to be `0`:

```
int sum = 0;
// sum == 0
int i= 0;
// Loop invariant: sum == 0 + 1 + ... i-1
while (i < 10) {
    // Loop invariant: sum == 0 + 1 + ... i-1
    sum += i;
    // sum == 0 + 1 + ... i
    i++;
    // Loop invariant: sum == 0 + 1 + ... i-1
}
// Loop invariant: sum == 0 + 1 + ... i-1, and i == 10 => sum == 0 + 1 + ... 9
```

As you see, the loop invariant is `sum == 0 + 1 + ... i-1`. It is (trivially) established before the loop, modified then restored in the loop, and true after the loop. Together with the loop exit condition (`i == 10`), it ensures the correctness (`sum == 45`).

Answer (score 0):

A loop invariant does not belong to the whole loop, but to one specific point in the loop. You'd write one loop invariant that is true just before the sum is increased, one that is true just after the sum is increased, one just after i is increased.

As you go through the statements of the loop, you get different invariants. The one at the end of the loop should then lead to the one at the start of the loop being correct when you re-enter the loop.

Comment: No, the loop invariant is uniquely defined and holds true before and after any iteration (it also has to hold when there are no iterations at all). Other conditions that remain true at places within the loop are also invariants but they are not used to prove the effect of the loop and will not be called loop invariants.

Comment: "it also has to hold when there are no iterations at all". Could anyone provide proof that this is correct, e.g. by citing some formal wikipedia definition where this is stated?